# Jquery extract certain href values from html

Tags: jquery, href

Somewhere in my page I have:

```
<td align="center">
    <a href="javascript:goToDetails(8719)">8719</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:goToDetails(8719)">Changes to Henderson Center Webpage</a>
</td>
```

I want to use jQuery to get all of the values of the `<a href="javascript:goToDetails(some int)">Value</a>` tags. So for the above code, I want to be able to extract the strings "8719" and "Changes to Henderson center Webpage".

Comment: How is this info populated? Dynamically?  Cuz then you could populate the 8719 into a data-id field, and then extract the html for the link name, and name all links you wanna find with a class of your choosing to scan for

Comment: It is added dynamically, but outside of my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector finds all `a` elements whose `href` attributes *ends with* `goToDetails(8719)`:

```
var values = $("a[href$='goToDetails(8719)']").map(function () {
     return $(this).html();   
}).get();
```

The contents of the anchors are returned into an array that you can manipulate or use as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `table` with those `a` elements you can use [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [**.get()**](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to populate them into an array of values, similar to this:

```
var myArray = $("table a").map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
              }).get();
```

Adjust the selector as required.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8vcB5/) - Using `.map()` and `.get()`

---

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's each function and iterate throughout the dom for the Text of all the Anchor tags. I've attached a sample fiddle of a scenario where they are all printed to screen on document ready to give you an idea. Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
       $("#result").append($(this).text() + "<br/>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danieljordan13/mkQJt/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/mSGVT/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(a[href*=goToDetails]).each(function() {

    var num = $(this).attr('href').match("[0-9]+"),
        text = $(this).text();

    alert(num + ": " + text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

gets an array of all link names and href number

```
var all_values = [];
$('a').each(function (i) {
    all_values.push( $(this).text() );
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    href = href.replace("javascript:goToDetails(", "");
    all_values.push( href.replace(")", "") );
});
alert(all_values);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qb9E3/